# Cannot instantiating a bean with a newer version of Java

Tags: java, spring

I am facing a project upgrade, and I'm struggling with a problem from many days. I really hope that some Spring expert can help.
Basically, this project is a Java application using Spring and ZK, deploied on Websphere.
The project was compiled with Java 7 running on Websphere with Java 7, now it have to be Java 8 to Java 8.

My problem happens at server startup:

```
[3/17/23 14:07:16:223 CET] 00000094 SystemOut     O [Default : 0] 14:07:16.222 | ERROR (Logger.java:37) - getSession error
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at it.reply.filenet.services.SuperUserService.getSession(SuperUserService.java:84)
    at it.reply.filenet.services.DataDictionaryService.init(DataDictionaryService.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1734)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:415)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1211)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:795)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1413)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2273)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5554)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5680)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor42.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:664)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:91)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

The `SuperUserService` is this, and it fails because `authenticationMgr` is null (note that when "Java 7 to 7" worked):

```
    @Override
    public Object getSession() {
        if (session != null) return session;
    
        try {
            ITrustedLoginManager trustedLoginManager = new TrustedLoginManager(loginFile);
            LoginInfo loginInfo = trustedLoginManager.getLoginInfo();
    
            if (authenticationMgr == null) {
                authenticationMgr = (IAuthenticationMgr) BeanFactory.getBean("SessionlessAuthenticationMgr");
            }
    
            session = (ObjectStore) authenticationMgr.generateSession(loginInfo.getUser(), loginInfo.getPassword(),
                    loginInfo.getRepository()); //LINE 84
        } catch (Exception e) {
            BeanFactory.getLogger().error(this, "getSession error", e);
        }
        return session;
    }
```

The BeanFactory.getBean(), which returns null:

```
    public static Object getBean(String beanName) {
        Object bean = null;
        try {
            bean = SpringUtil.getBean(beanName);
        } catch (org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException e) {
            WebApplicationContext context = null;
            try {
                HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
                        .getRequest();
                context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request.getSession().getServletContext());
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                // ignore, returns null
                // Logger.getRootLogger().debug("Eccezione ignorata - getBean: " + beanName);
            }
            if (context != null) {
                bean = context.getBean(beanName);
            } else {
                try {
                    bean = SpringApplicationContext.getBean(beanName); //<-- RETURNS NULL HERE, BECAUSE THERE'S NO CONTEXT
                } catch (BeanCreationException ex) {
                        Logger.getRootLogger().warn(beanName
                                + " - E' richiesta la creazione del bean in un contesto non valido. Nota: è possibile che il chiamante ignori l'errore",
                                ex);
                    } else {
                        Logger.getRootLogger()
                                .warn("Problema in creazione del bean spring tramite SpringApplicationContext", ex);
                    }
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    Logger.getRootLogger().warn(
                            "Eccezione non gestita in creazione del bean spring tramite SpringApplicationContext", t);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return bean;
    }
```

The SpringApplicationContext:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

/**
 * Wrapper to always return a reference to the Spring Application Context from within non-Spring enabled beans. Unlike
 * Spring MVC's WebApplicationContextUtils we do not need a reference to the Servlet context for this. All we need is
 * for this bean to be initialized during application startup.
 */
public class SpringApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;

    /**
     * This method is called from within the ApplicationContext once it is done starting up, it will stick a reference
     * to itself into this bean.
     *
     * @param context
     *            a reference to the ApplicationContext.
     */
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        System.out.println(
                "_____________________________ SpringApplicationContext - calling setApplicationContext _____________________________");
        if (Logger.getRootLogger().isDebugEnabled()) Logger.getRootLogger()
                .debug("SpringApplicationContext - calling setApplicationContext");
        System.out.println("SpringApplicationContext - calling setApplicationContext");
        CONTEXT = context;
    }

    /**
     * This is about the same as context.getBean("beanName"), except it has its own static handle to the Spring context,
     * so calling this method statically will give access to the beans by name in the Spring application context. As in
     * the context.getBean("beanName") call, the caller must cast to the appropriate target class. If the bean does not
     * exist, then a Runtime error will be thrown.
     *
     * @param beanName
     *            the name of the bean to get.
     * @return an Object reference to the named bean.
     */
    public static Object getBean(String beanName) {
        if (CONTEXT != null) {
            //System.out.println("start getBean Spring di " + beanName);
            return CONTEXT.getBean(beanName);
        } else {
            //System.out.println("No CONTEXT defined in SpringApplicationContext");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

When entering the `getBean()`, `CONTEXT` is null, because `setApplicationContext()` is never launched!

The project was compiled with some very old jars:

[image]

So, I have updated them with the 3.2.16 version (I read in some other thread that it's the minimum version for Java 8):

[image]

Unfortunately, the problem is the same.

Some other info.
Part of my applicationContext (note that `GlobalCacheService` and `GlobalPropertiesService` are instantiated, with both versions of Spring):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="GlobalCacheService" scope="singleton" class="it.reply.services.GlobalCacheService" />
    
    <bean id="ObjectsAttrsDef" scope="singleton" class="it.reply.filenet.entities.ObjectsAttrsDef" />
    
    <bean id="ObjectActionService" scope="singleton" class="it.reply.client.services.actions.ObjectActionService"/>
    
    <bean id="GlobalPropertiesService" scope="singleton" class="it.reply.services.GlobalPropertiesService" init-method="init" >
        <property name="propertiesFiles" value="${geno.global.properties}" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="SessionlessAuthenticationMgr" scope="singleton" parent="AuthenticationMgr" >
        <property name="sessionless" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="DataDictionaryService" scope="singleton" class="it.reply.filenet.services.DataDictionaryService" init-method="init">
        <property name="globalPropertiesService" ref="GlobalPropertiesService" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="AuthenticationMgr" scope="session" class="it.reply.client.filenet.authentication.ClientAuthenticationMgr" init-method="init" >
        <property name="globalPropertiesService" ref="GlobalPropertiesService" />
        <property name="userService" ref="UserService" />
        <property name="objectStoreName" value="${login.objectStore.name}" />
        <property name="objectStoreUri" value="${login.objectStore.uri}" />
        <property name="contentEngineTransport" value="${login.objectStore.transport}" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Even the `init()` of `AuthenticationMgr` is called and it ends propertly, wih both versions of Spring, because I can log it.

I know that the problem is complex and my question could lack of some information, but please, if you need some other info about my project, an help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve my issue. Basically, my application has a lot of Spring context files:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

The `DataDictionaryService`, which wasn't starting, was defined - in one of those - this way (as I told in the question):

```
<bean id="DataDictionaryService" scope="singleton" class="it.reply.filenet.services.DataDictionaryService" init-method="init">
        <property name="globalPropertiesService" ref="GlobalPropertiesService" />
</bean>
```

This depends on `SpringApplicationContext` (for initializing the context), and it is defined (in another xml) like this:

```
<bean id="SpringApplicationContext" class="it.reply.bean.SpringApplicationContext" scope="singleton"/>
```

For some reasons, when on Java 7, `SpringApplicationContext` was started at first. On Java 8, this does not happen. Almost for sure, the Spring classloader has a different logic among different JREs, regarding implicit Beans' taxonomy.

I solved by specifing the `depends-on` attribute:

```
<bean id="DataDictionaryService" scope="singleton" class="it.reply.filenet.services.DataDictionaryService" init-method="init" depends-on="SpringApplicationContext">
    <property name="globalPropertiesService" ref="GlobalPropertiesService" />
</bean>
```

I've also been able to keep the version 3.1.x of Spring.

Many thanks to the people who tried to help me out!

Answer (score 1):

The `SessionlessAuthenticationMgr` (scope="singleton") has a parent `AuthenticationMgr` (scope="session").

I suspect that the scope of `AuthenticationMgr` should also be `singleton` and not `session`.

Perhaps older jdk was less strict about this?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help: I've tried, but unfortunately this doesn't change the error.

Comment: Just want to say that, despite it wasn't the correct answer, you really gave me a useful hint. Someway, the Beans inside my application contexts where loaded in different order between Java 7 and 8, so yes, there was something more strict in Java 8. I had to explicit a "depends-on" attribute. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that problem lays in *AuthenticationMgr* scope session. You've updated Spring version from 3.1 to 3.2. Spring 3.2.0 [release notes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/changelog.txt) says that:

> child bean definition's scope attribute can be inherited from parent bean definition now

Your *SessionlessAuthenticationMgr* parent is  *AuthenticationMgr* with session scope. It still doesn't answer the question why getBean returns null, but you definitely should check what is going on here

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Basically, the sessionless is used for autenthication (towards FileNet) with superuser, at the startup of the server. The "non sessionless" is used for managing the sessions of users via navigation on the web app. Consider that it always worked with Java 7.

Comment: Have you tried to use Java 8 with 3.1 jars? Or Java 7 with 3.2 jars?

Comment: I've just tried:
- Server Java 7 + app Java 7 + libs 3.1 (working)

- Server Java 8 + app Java 7 + libs 3.1 (not working)

- Server Java 8 + app Java 8 + libs 3.1 (not working)

- Server Java 8 + app Java 8 + libs 3.2 (not working)

Comment: Same error everywhere? Server Java 8 + app Java 7/8 + libs 3.1 fails with the same error we are getting somewhere, it means 100% that Java version bump break something

Comment: Exactly. Always the the same NullPointer when trying to instantiate the authenticationMgr.

Comment: Okay, just to clarify. What is null on line 84? _authenticationMgr_ or _loginInfo_ object? And try please Java 7 + Java 7 + libs 3.2 to ensure that libs are ok

Comment: Yes, it's the authenticationMgr. It fails the BeanFactory.getBean() and it returns null. Thank you so much for your effort in helping me.

Comment: (I've added more info to my question)

Comment: So line *SpringApplicationContext.getBean(beanName)* returns null. When app is working correctly, bean is received through line *context.getBean(beanName);* or through another one?

Comment: I confim. I also added the SpringApplicationContext.

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere. Jeez, what a mess, haha. Seems like context isn't saved to CONTEXT variable. Is method setApplicationContext called? First stupid idea is to try to create listener for ContextStartedEvent, set context manually and see what will happen

Comment: In fact. Looks like setApplicationContext is not call as soon as the server starts up. :( that's the difference between the two Java versions' behaviour on server.

Comment: It would be interesting to dig up why it stopped calling. Maybe some changes in reflection API? Anyway, it will takes too long, so I suggest to you to write listeners in xml config and see what will be changed. Good luck!